# Distinguish between local function calls and external(imported) function calls in a dynamic trace

Tags: ida, disassembly, binary-analysis, patch-reversing, function-hooking

I know that when IDA pro want to disassemble a binary and label the functions, employs import address table and IDA flirt to distinguish from local functions and external functions!

Now I have dynamice trace and want to distinguish between local and external function calls but I do not know how can I do this process. Could you please help me how can I do this process?

My trace is something like this:(this is a small part of trace)

```
(1) 7c90e430: lea 0x10(%esp),%edi   A@0x0022fd30[0x00000000][4](R) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)    R@edi[0x00310031][4](W) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)   
(2) 7c90e434: pop %eax  M@0x0022fd20[0x7c901166][4](R) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)    R@eax[0x00401130][4](W) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)   
(3) 7c90e435: call %eax R@eax[0x7c901166][4](R) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)   M@0x0022fd20[0x7c901166][4](W) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)    
(4) 7c901166: lea 0x10(%esp),%eax   A@0x0022fd30[0x00000000][4](R) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)    R@eax[0x7c901166][4](W) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)   
(5) 7c90116a: mov %eax,0x4(%esp)    R@eax[0x0022fd30][4](R) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)   M@0x0022fd24[0x00000000][4](W) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)    
(6) 7c90116e: xor %ebp,%ebp R@ebp[0x00350037][4](R) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)   R@ebp[0x00350037][4](RW) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)  
(7) 7c901170: jmp 0x7c91b057    J@0x00000000[0x00019ee7][4](R) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)    
(8) 7c91b057: mov %edi,%edi R@edi[0x0022fd30][4](R) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)   R@edi[0x0022fd30][4](W) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)   
(9) 7c91b059: push %ebp R@ebp[0x00000000][4](R) T_
(33) 7c9222f9: pushl $0x7c97b0c8    I@0x00000000[0x7c97b0c8][4](R) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)    M@0x0022fd04[0x00000000][4](W) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)    
(34) 7c9222fe: call 0x7c9199d7  J@0x00000000[0xffff76d9][4](R) T_begin (0x0) T_end begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)  M@0x0022fd1c[0x00000000][4](W) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)    
(10) 7c91b05a: mov %esp,%ebp    R@esp[0x0022fd1c][4](R) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)   R@ebp[0x00000000][4](W) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)   
(11) 7c91b05c: cmpb $0x0,0x7c97b20c I@0x00000000[0x00000000][1](R) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)    M@0x7c97b20c[0x00000000][1](R) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)    
(12) 7c91b063: jz 0x7c9226ed    J@0x00000000[0x0000768a][4](R) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)    
(13) 7c9226ed: call 0x7c9226fc  J@0x00000000[0x0000000f][4](R) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)    M@0x0022fd18[0x00000000][4](W) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)    
(14) 7c9226fc: mov %edi,%edi    R@edi[0x0022fd30][4](R) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)   R@edi[0x0022fd30][4](W) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)   
(15) 7c9226fe: push %ebp    R@ebp[0x0022fd1c][4](R) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)   M@0x0022fd14[0x00000000][4](W) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)    
(16) 7c9226ff: mov %esp,%ebp    R@esp[0x0022fd14][4](R) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)   R@ebp[0x0022fd1c][4](W) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)   
(17) 7c922701: push %ecx    R@ecx[0x00310038][4](R) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)   M@0x0022fd10[0x00000000][4](W) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)    
(18) 7c922702: push %ecx    R@ecx[0x00310038][4](R) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)   M@0x0022fd0c[0x00000000][4](W) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)    
(19) 7c922703: xor %ecx,%ecx    R@ecx[0x00310038][4](R) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)   R@ecx[0x00310038][4](RW) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)  
(20) 7c922705: mov $0x7c97d394,%eax I@0x00000000[0x7c97d394][4](R) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)    R@eax[0x0022fd30][4](W) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)   
(21) 7c92270a: inc %ecx R@ecx[0x00000000][4](RW) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)  
(22) 7c92270b: xadd %ecx,(%eax) R@ecx[0x00000001][4](RW) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)  M@0x7c97d394[0x00000000][4](RW) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)   
(23) 7c92270b: xadd %ecx,(%eax) R@ecx[0x00000001][4](RW) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)  M@0x7c97d394[0x00000000][4](RW) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)   
(24) 7c92270f: inc %ecx R@ecx[0x00000000][4](RW) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)  
(25) 7c922710: cmp $0x1,%ecx    I@0x00000000[0x00000001][1](R) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)    R@ecx[0x00000001][4](R) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)   
(26) 7c922713: jnz 0x7c93d4d9   J@0x00000000[0x0001adc6][4](R) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)    
(27) 7c922719: call 0x7c9222e9  J@0x00000000[0xfffffbd0][4](R) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)    M@0x0022fd08[0x00000000][4](W) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)    
(28) 7c9222e9: mov 0x7c97b0c8,%eax  M@0x7c97b0c8[0x0000bb40][4](R) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)    R@eax[0x7c97d394][4](W) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)   
(29) 7c9222ee: test %eax,%eax   R@eax[0x0000bb40][4](R) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)   R@eax[0x0000bb40][4](R) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)   
(30) 7c9222f0: jz 0x7c9222f9    J@0x00000000[0x00000009][4](R) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)    
(31) 7c9222f2: cmp $0xbb40,%eax I@0x00000000[0x0000bb40][4](R) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)    R@eax[0x0000bb40][4](R) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)   
(32) 7c9222f7: jnz 0x7c922309   J@0x00000000[0x00000012][4](R) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)    (0x0)   M@0x0022fd00[0x00000000][4](W) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)    
(35) 7c9199d7: pushb $0xc   I@0x00000000[0x0000000c][1](R) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)    M@0x0022fcfc[0x00000000][4](W) T_begin (0x0) T_end (0x0)
```

P.S: I should mention that I do not have any other information except this trace file.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say this is an external function because of the memory range (0x7c000000 looks typical for imported DLLs), but without more information it's actually hard to tell.

The proper way would be to check the memory sections of your binary and to see in which sections the current instructions are.